# Rewritting a path - duplicate the backslash "\"

Tags: python, replace, path, url-rewriting

Let's say that I have this path :

```
path = "\\main\user\program\mathlab\test\count"
```

I want to rewrite this path to be able to use it. So I need to duplicate the backslash to get :

```
new_path = "\\\main\\user\\program\\mathlab\\test\\count"
```

Comment: `path = "\" + path` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
path.replace("\\", "\\\\") # replaces each \ with \\
```

We need two backslashes to represent one actual backslash. This is because a single backslash starts an escape sequence (of 2 characters total) that gives you the ability to represent characters like whitespaces (e.g. `\n` for newline, `\t` for tabs, ...). If you need it to give you a slash, you will have to add another slash to finish the sequence.